# Что происходит, после запуска, например, цикла foreach в железе компьютера?

Tags: php, ассемблер, железо, процессор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выглядит реализация цикла foreach PHP или условие if, если через уровни абстракции мы спускаемся до железа? Что происходит при переводе всех этих команд в двоичный код и отправке технике?

Comment: Причем тут PHP и TCP? Вам надо на ассемблер смотреть. И к передаче данных это не имеет отношения.

Comment: "как выглядит реализация цикла foreach PHP или условие if" - ну просто берите любой учебник по ассемблеру и смотрите как реализуется цикл или проверка условия. "Что происходит при переводе всех этих команд в двоичный код и отправке технике?" - вот это вообще не понятно.

Comment: Вообще, для понимания низкоуровневых вещей на самом простом уровне я обычно советую почитать "Код. Тайный язык информатики" Петцольда

Comment: @insolor боюсь, пхпшный foreach будет выглядеть *немножко* сложнее чем цикл из учебника )

Comment: А если забить на JIT, то вообще никак не будет выглядеть, потому что, если я ничего не путаю, там виртуальная машина будет интерпретировать байткод

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, опять все накинулись(

Comment: @eanmos да, не понятно за что минус...

Comment: @andreymal, так-то да, но начинать стоит с более простых вещей

Comment: Ответ тянет на пару глав из книжки, а практическая польза стремится к 0.

Comment: Друзья, это хороший вопрос, на него можно дать квалифицированный ответ, например по C# на такой вопрос я бы ответил без проблем, не вижу причин для минусов или закрытия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация цикла foreach и условия if в PHP, когда код переводится в двоичный код и отправляется на выполнение на аппаратном уровне, будет зависеть от архитектуры процессора и операционной системы, на которых выполняется PHP-скрипт. Однако, в целом, PHP-код, включая циклы foreach и условия if, компилируется в промежуточное представление, такое как байт-код или опкод, перед тем как быть выполняемым на процессоре.

Когда промежуточное представление PHP-кода выполняется на процессоре, инструкции циклов foreach и условий if могут быть преобразованы в соответствующие машинные инструкции процессора, которые выполняют необходимые операции. Например, инструкции цикла foreach могут быть преобразованы в машинные инструкции, которые выполняют итерацию по массиву или другому итерируемому объекту, проверяют условие остановки цикла и выполняют операции внутри цикла. А инструкции условия if могут быть преобразованы в машинные инструкции, которые выполняют сравнение значений и осуществляют переход в определенный блок кода, в зависимости от результата сравнения.

Конкретные детали реализации цикла foreach и условия if на уровне аппаратного обеспечения могут варьироваться в зависимости от архитектуры процессора, такой как x86, ARM, MIPS и т. д., и операционной системы, на которой выполняется PHP-скрипт. Однако, в общих чертах, циклы foreach и условия if в PHP преобразовываются в соответствующие машинные инструкции процессора, чтобы выполнять необходимые операции на уровне аппаратного обеспечения.

Если интересует то, как реализован интерпретатор PHP, то можешь посмотреть исходный код на гитхабе https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: Chat GPT? Или я не прав?

Comment: _Уважаемые адерпты PHP. Я вижу ваши тревоги и понимаю беспокойство по поводу качества данного ответа. Однако предлагаю его оставить в живых. Из опций: 1) этот ответ можно улучшить, добавив в него больше полезной информации и выбросить лишнюю воду, он может оказаться полезным для будущих посетителей; 2) можно добавить другой ответ, который будет сформулирован "как надо". Уважаемый автор ответа, старайтесь избегать таких перепостов в будущем и формулировать ответы самостоятельно._